# Windows XP - wifi driver randomly breaking

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, drivers

I have a Dell D430 running a fresh Windows XP install. The problem is that in random intervals the wifi connection breaks. Not only it disconnects, but it refuses to detect any wifi network. Disabling and reenabling the connection helps most of the time, but doing it every 5-30 minutes is rather distracting. Prior to the Windows reinstall the problem didn't occur.

The laptop is running Windows XP SP3 with all updates installed. The wifi card is Intel Pro Wireless 3945 ABG. Driver vwersion is 12.4.4.5, located in Windows\system32\Drivers\NETw5x32.sys.

My steps so far (which didn't help):

- Redownloaded official Intel drivers (R257701, version stamp says 2010) from Dell's site, reinstalled
- Installing with / without the connection management software that comes bundled with the installer
- Purged the above two points using Revo Uninstaller Pro (trial) and deleting the driver, then reinstalling with multiple restarts in between
- Switched off "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" in the driver power management tab
- Checked Windows Event log for anything suspicious, and didn't find any driver crash event, but there is one a-bit-related spammer:

  The description for Event ID ( 5005 ) in Source ( NETw5x32 ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: ; \DEVICE{7F306B34-BEAA-43DD-838E-74695F7FDFCB}.

This event occurs multiple times in the event log, and the "Source" is NETw5x32 which seems to be the wifi driver.

### Anyways...

I understand this question is pretty localised. But I'm running out of options - could you point me in a new direction to search? Or maybe name the problem I am facing - is it a know Intel wifi driver issue? Is it hardware failure? Could you try an educated guess?

Comment: I'm just curious, why are you still running XP?

Comment: Long live Win XP!

Comment: Have you updated your BIOS lately?  Or try a slightly older Wifi driver

Comment: Sort of sounds like the DNS Server is playing up in the router....Check router DNS settings and whether your PC has a static IP or not.  (Remove MACs from your network while you troubleshoot)